# I am getting an error in the following program, and I am not sure what is to be done

Tags: c++

The code is given as follows:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>
#include <cmath>
using namespace std;
inline void keep_window_open() { char ch; cin >> ch; }
int main()
{
  string operation;
  double num1, num2, val;
  cout << "Enter the operation followed by the numbers\n";
  cin >> operation >> num1 >> num2 >> endl;
  if (operation == "+") {
    cout << operation << num1 << num2 << endl;
    val = num1 + num2;
    cout << val << endl;
  }
  if (operation == "-") {
    cout << operation << num1 << num2 << endl;
    val = num1 - num2;
    cout << val << endl;
   }
  if (operation == "*") {
    cout << operation << num1 << num2 << endl;
    val = num1 * num2;
    cout << val << endl;
  }
  if (operation == "/") {
    cout << operation << num1 << num2 << endl;
    val = num1 / num2;
    cout << val << endl;
  }
}
```

I am getting the following error:

```
operands.cpp: In function ‘int main()’:
operands.cpp:13:39: error: no match for ‘operator>>’ in ‘(&(& std::operator>> [with     _CharT = char, _Traits = std::char_traits<char>, _Alloc = std::allocator<char>]((* & std::cin), (* & operation)))->std::basic_istream<_CharT, _Traits>::operator>> [with _CharT = char, _Traits = std::char_traits<char>, std::basic_istream<_CharT, _Traits>::__istream_type = std::basic_istream<char>]((* & num1)))->std::basic_istream<_CharT, _Traits>::operator>> [with _CharT = char, _Traits = std::char_traits<char>, std::basic_istream<_CharT, _Traits>::__istream_type = std::basic_istream<char>]((* & num2)) >> std::endl’
operands.cpp:13:39: note: candidates are:
/usr/include/c++/4.6/istream:122:7: note: std::basic_istream<_CharT, _Traits>::__istream_type& std::basic_istream<_CharT, _Traits>::operator>>(std::basic_istream<_CharT, _Traits>::__istream_type& (*)(std::basic_istream<_CharT, _Traits>::__istream_type&)) [with _CharT = char, _Traits = std::char_traits<char>, std::basic_istream<_CharT, _Traits>::__istream_type = std::basic_istream<char>]
/usr/include/c++/4.6/istream:122:7: note:   no known conversion for argument 1 from ‘<unresolved overloaded function type>’ to ‘std::basic_istream<char>::__istream_type& (*)(std::basic_istream<char>::__istream_type&) {aka std::basic_istream<char>& (*)(std::basic_istream<char>&)}’
/usr/include/c++/4.6/istream:126:7: note: std::basic_istream<_CharT, _Traits>::__istream_type& std::basic_istream<_CharT, _Traits>::operator>>(std::basic_istream<_CharT, _Traits>::__ios_type& (*)(std::basic_istream<_CharT, _Traits>::__ios_type&)) [with _CharT = char, _Traits = std::char_traits<char>, std::basic_istream<_CharT, _Traits>::__istream_type = std::basic_istream<char>, std::basic_istream<_CharT, _Traits>::__ios_type = std::basic_ios<char>]
/usr/include/c++/4.6/istream:126:7: note:   no known conversion for argument 1 from ‘<unresolved overloaded function type>’ to ‘std::basic_istream<char>::__ios_type& (*)(std::basic_istream<char>::__ios_type&) {aka std::basic_ios<char>& (*)(std::basic_ios<char>&)}’
/usr/include/c++/4.6/istream:133:7: note: std::basic_istream<_CharT, _Traits>::__istream_type& std::basic_istream<_CharT, _Traits>::operator>>(std::ios_base& (*)(std::ios_base&)) [with _CharT = char, _Traits = std::char_traits<char>, std::basic_istream<_CharT, _Traits>::__istream_type = std::basic_istream<char>]
/usr/include/c++/4.6/istream:133:7: note:   no known conversion for argument 1 from ‘<unresolved overloaded function type>’ to ‘std::ios_base& (*)(std::ios_base&)’
/usr/include/c++/4.6/istream:169:7: note: std::basic_istream<_CharT, _Traits>::__istream_type& std::basic_istream<_CharT, _Traits>::operator>>(bool&) [with _CharT = char, _Traits = std::char_traits<char>, std::basic_istream<_CharT, _Traits>::__istream_type = std::basic_istream<char>]
/usr/include/c++/4.6/istream:169:7: note:   no known conversion for argument 1 from ‘<unresolved overloaded function type>’ to ‘bool&’
/usr/include/c++/4.6/istream:173:7: note: std::basic_istream<_CharT, _Traits>& std::basic_istream<_CharT, _Traits>::operator>>(short int&) [with _CharT = char, _Traits = std::char_traits<char>]
/usr/include/c++/4.6/istream:173:7: note:   no known conversion for argument 1 from ‘<unresolved overloaded function type>’ to ‘short int&’
/usr/include/c++/4.6/istream:176:7: note: std::basic_istream<_CharT, _Traits>::__istream_type& std::basic_istream<_CharT, _Traits>::operator>>(short unsigned int&) [with _CharT = char, _Traits = std::char_traits<char>, std::basic_istream<_CharT, _Traits>::__istream_type = std::basic_istream<char>]
/usr/include/c++/4.6/istream:176:7: note:   no known conversion for argument 1 from ‘<unresolved overloaded function type>’ to ‘short unsigned int&’
/usr/include/c++/4.6/istream:180:7: note: std::basic_istream<_CharT, _Traits>& std::basic_istream<_CharT, _Traits>::operator>>(int&) [with _CharT = char, _Traits = std::char_traits<char>]
/usr/include/c++/4.6/istream:180:7: note:   no known conversion for argument 1 from ‘<unresolved overloaded function type>’ to ‘int&’
/usr/include/c++/4.6/istream:183:7: note: std::basic_istream<_CharT, _Traits>::__istream_type& std::basic_istream<_CharT, _Traits>::operator>>(unsigned int&) [with _CharT = char, _Traits = std::char_traits<char>, std::basic_istream<_CharT, _Traits>::__istream_type = std::basic_istream<char>]
/usr/include/c++/4.6/istream:183:7: note:   no known conversion for argument 1 from ‘<unresolved overloaded function type>’ to ‘unsigned int&’
/usr/include/c++/4.6/istream:187:7: note: std::basic_istream<_CharT, _Traits>::__istream_type& std::basic_istream<_CharT, _Traits>::operator>>(long int&) [with _CharT = char, _Traits = std::char_traits<char>, std::basic_istream<_CharT, _Traits>::__istream_type = std::basic_istream<char>]
/usr/include/c++/4.6/istream:187:7: note:   no known conversion for argument 1 from ‘<unresolved overloaded function type>’ to ‘long int&’
/usr/include/c++/4.6/istream:191:7: note: std::basic_istream<_CharT, _Traits>::__istream_type& std::basic_istream<_CharT, _Traits>::operator>>(long unsigned int&) [with _CharT = char, _Traits = std::char_traits<char>, std::basic_istream<_CharT, _Traits>::__istream_type = std::basic_istream<char>]
/usr/include/c++/4.6/istream:191:7: note:   no known conversion for argument 1 from ‘<unresolved overloaded function type>’ to ‘long unsigned int&’
/usr/include/c++/4.6/istream:196:7: note: std::basic_istream<_CharT, _Traits>::__istream_type& std::basic_istream<_CharT, _Traits>::operator>>(long long int&) [with _CharT = char, _Traits = std::char_traits<char>, std::basic_istream<_CharT, _Traits>::__istream_type = std::basic_istream<char>]
/usr/include/c++/4.6/istream:196:7: note:   no known conversion for argument 1 from ‘<unresolved overloaded function type>’ to ‘long long int&’
/usr/include/c++/4.6/istream:200:7: note: std::basic_istream<_CharT, _Traits>::__istream_type& std::basic_istream<_CharT, _Traits>::operator>>(long long unsigned int&) [with _CharT = char, _Traits = std::char_traits<char>, std::basic_istream<_CharT, _Traits>::__istream_type = std::basic_istream<char>]
/usr/include/c++/4.6/istream:200:7: note:   no known conversion for argument 1 from ‘<unresolved overloaded function type>’ to ‘long long unsigned int&’
/usr/include/c++/4.6/istream:205:7: note: std::basic_istream<_CharT, _Traits>::__istream_type& std::basic_istream<_CharT, _Traits>::operator>>(float&) [with _CharT = char, _Traits = std::char_traits<char>, std::basic_istream<_CharT, _Traits>::__istream_type = std::basic_istream<char>]
/usr/include/c++/4.6/istream:205:7: note:   no known conversion for argument 1 from ‘<unresolved overloaded function type>’ to ‘float&’
/usr/include/c++/4.6/istream:209:7: note: std::basic_istream<_CharT, _Traits>::__istream_type& std::basic_istream<_CharT, _Traits>::operator>>(double&) [with _CharT = char, _Traits = std::char_traits<char>, std::basic_istream<_CharT, _Traits>::__istream_type = std::basic_istream<char>]
/usr/include/c++/4.6/istream:209:7: note:   no known conversion for argument 1 from ‘<unresolved overloaded function type>’ to ‘double&’
/usr/include/c++/4.6/istream:213:7: note: std::basic_istream<_CharT, _Traits>::__istream_type& std::basic_istream<_CharT, _Traits>::operator>>(long double&) [with _CharT = char, _Traits = std::char_traits<char>, std::basic_istream<_CharT, _Traits>::__istream_type = std::basic_istream<char>]
/usr/include/c++/4.6/istream:213:7: note:   no known conversion for argument 1 from ‘<unresolved overloaded function type>’ to ‘long double&’
/usr/include/c++/4.6/istream:217:7: note: std::basic_istream<_CharT, _Traits>::__istream_type& std::basic_istream<_CharT, _Traits>::operator>>(void*&) [with _CharT = char, _Traits = std::char_traits<char>, std::basic_istream<_CharT, _Traits>::__istream_type = std::basic_istream<char>]
/usr/include/c++/4.6/istream:217:7: note:   no known conversion for argument 1 from ‘<unresolved overloaded function type>’ to ‘void*&’
/usr/include/c++/4.6/istream:241:7: note: std::basic_istream<_CharT, _Traits>& std::basic_istream<_CharT, _Traits>::operator>>(std::basic_istream<_CharT, _Traits>::__streambuf_type*) [with _CharT = char, _Traits = std::char_traits<char>, std::basic_istream<_CharT, _Traits>::__streambuf_type = std::basic_streambuf<char>]
/usr/include/c++/4.6/istream:241:7: note:   no known conversion for argument 1 from ‘<unresolved overloaded function type>’ to ‘std::basic_istream<char>::__streambuf_type* {aka std::basic_streambuf<char>*}’
/usr/include/c++/4.6/bits/basic_string.tcc:998:5: note: template<class _CharT, class _Traits, class _Alloc> std::basic_istream<_CharT, _Traits>& std::operator>>(std::basic_istream<_CharT, _Traits>&, std::basic_string<_CharT, _Traits, _Alloc>&)
/usr/include/c++/4.6/istream:752:5: note: std::basic_istream<_CharT2, _Traits2>& std::operator>>(std::basic_istream<_CharT2, _Traits2>&, _CharT2*) [with _CharT2 = char, _Traits2 = std::char_traits<char>, _CharT = char, _Traits = std::char_traits<char>]
/usr/include/c++/4.6/istream:752:5: note:   no known conversion for argument 2 from ‘<unresolved overloaded function type>’ to ‘char*’
/usr/include/c++/4.6/bits/istream.tcc:925:5: note: std::basic_istream<_CharT, _Traits>& std::operator>>(std::basic_istream<_CharT, _Traits>&, _CharT&) [with _CharT = char, _Traits = std::char_traits<char>]
/usr/include/c++/4.6/bits/istream.tcc:925:5: note:   no known conversion for argument 2 from ‘<unresolved overloaded function type>’ to ‘char&’
/usr/include/c++/4.6/istream:709:5: note: template<class _Traits> std::basic_istream<char, _Traits>& std::operator>>(std::basic_istream<char, _Traits>&, unsigned char&)
/usr/include/c++/4.6/istream:714:5: note: template<class _Traits> std::basic_istream<char, _Traits>& std::operator>>(std::basic_istream<char, _Traits>&, signed char&)
/usr/include/c++/4.6/istream:756:5: note: template<class _Traits> std::basic_istream<char, _Traits>& std::operator>>(std::basic_istream<char, _Traits>&, unsigned char*)
/usr/include/c++/4.6/istream:761:5: note: template<class _Traits> std::basic_istream<char, _Traits>& std::operator>>(std::basic_istream<char, _Traits>&, signed char*)
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Don't put `>> endl` after `cin` ! That is, replace

```
cin >> operation >> num1 >> num2 >> endl;
```

with

```
cin >> operation >> num1 >> num2;
```